# Convert a time string eg "Wed, 24 Nov 2010 13:10:00 EST" to DataTime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am parsing a XML , and I get the created time as: Wed, 24 Nov 2010 13:10:00 EST

My requirement is to convert this time into the specified time format using DateTime function before inserting it in the database.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks you
Zeeshan

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert one date into another date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a time string eg "Wed, 24 Nov 2010 13:10:00 EST" to DataTime in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288767/convert-a-time-string-eg-wed-24-nov-2010-131000-est-to-datatime-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the duplicate link I pointed out above.

The `r` date format *might* work for you - not sure because of the time zone name. If in doubt, build the mask yourself, using `e` as a placeholder for the time zone identifier.

The [PHP manual on date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has the list of placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Use [date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function to get DateTime. Your format looks like "D, d M y H:i:s T".