# Convert a time string eg "Wed, 24 Nov 2010 13:10:00 EST" to DataTime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am parsing a xml, and I get the created time as: Wed, 24 Nov 2010 13:10:00 EST

My requirement is to convert this time into the specified time format using DateTime function before inserting it in the database.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks you
Zeeshan

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288764/convert-a-time-string-eg-wed-24-nov-2010-131000-est-to-datatime-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set EST timezone

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
   ```
2. convert to epoch

   ```
   $epoch = strtotime('Wed, 24 Nov 2010 13:10:00 EST');
   ```
3. get date/time

   ```
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $epoch);
   ```